# Fail to convert xml into JAVA class

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml response and want it to convert into java class for android usage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>
    <results_info>
        <page>1</page>
        <total_pages>8</total_pages>
    </results_info>
    <listing_info>
        <id>4</id>
        <image></image>
    </listing_info>
    <listing_info>
        <id>4</id>
        <image></image>
    </listing_info>
    <listing_info>
        <id>4</id>
        <image></image>
    </listing_info>
</title>
```

This is the code use for data fetch

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("myUrl")
    Call<MyObject> reqProfile();
}
Api WEB_SERVICE = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.baseUrl.com/")
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
        .build().create(Api.class);
```

how can I make a model class of **MyObject** for it

Comment: So what's the issue? Post the code that you tried along with the error.

Comment: You have to parse the xml with for example XmlPullparser

Comment: I am working with retrofit for xml parsing

Comment: post your java object

Comment: I have required a java class for model class, so i can send it to retrofit

Answer (score 2):

Thank you developers for interesting in the question, and finally after a lot of struggle I got to the point and solve this problem here is JAVA class of this xml.
I have created three classes for efficient work.

1: MyObject

```
public class MyObject {
    @Element(name = "results_info")
    private Results_info results_info;
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    List<Listing_info> listing_info;
}
```

2: Results_info

```
public class Results_info {
    private String page;
    private String total_pages;
}
```

3: Listing_info

```
public class Listing_info {
    @Element(required = false)
    String id;
    @Element(required = false)
    String image;
    @Element(required = false)
}
```

@Element(required = false) is due to some time data may be empty.

And in response in call manager of retrofit, we can get all the data from accessing objects of these classes just like

```
...
if (response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
    MyObject object = (MyObject) response.body();
    String page = object.getResults_info().getPage();
    List<Listing_info> myList = object.getList();
    String a = myList.get(0).getImage();
}
...
```

Cheers.